# Initializing an array of objects, out of range error

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm starting to learn C# and I have a problem with initializing an array of objects.

namespace DayAtTheRaces

{

```
public partial class ADayAtTheRacesForm : Form
{
    Guy[] guysArray = new Guy[2];
    Greyhound[] greyhoundsArray=new Greyhound[3];


    public ADayAtTheRacesForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
      
        guysArray[0] = new Guy { myName="Joe", MyCashInBank=50, myRadioButton=JoeRadioButton, myLabel=JoeBetLable, myBet=null };
        guysArray[1] = new Guy { myName = "Rob", MyCashInBank = 75, myRadioButton = RobRadioButton, myLabel = RobBetLabel, myBet = null };
        guysArray[2] = new Guy { myName = "Al", MyCashInBank = 45, myRadioButton = AlRadioButton, myLabel = AlBetLabel, myBet = null };

        greyhoundsArray[0] = new Greyhound { myPictureBox = DogPictureBox1, myRaceTrackPosition = DogPictureBox1.Left, raceTrackLength = RaceTrackPictureBox.Width - DogPictureBox1.Width, randomValue = null };
        greyhoundsArray[1] = new Greyhound { myPictureBox = DogPictureBox2, myRaceTrackPosition = DogPictureBox2.Left, raceTrackLength = RaceTrackPictureBox.Width - DogPictureBox2.Width, randomValue = null };
        greyhoundsArray[2] = new Greyhound { myPictureBox = DogPictureBox3, myRaceTrackPosition = DogPictureBox3.Left, raceTrackLength = RaceTrackPictureBox.Width - DogPictureBox3.Width, randomValue = null };
        greyhoundsArray[3] = new Greyhound { myPictureBox = DogPictureBox4, myRaceTrackPosition = DogPictureBox4.Left, raceTrackLength = RaceTrackPictureBox.Width - DogPictureBox4.Width, randomValue = null };

        for (int i = 0; i<= 2; i++)
        {
            guysArray[i].ChangeLabel();
            guysArray[i].ChangeRadio();
        }
    }

    
    private void RaceButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<=3; i++)
        {
            greyhoundsArray[i].TakeStartingPosition();
        }
    }

    private void BetsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       for(int i=0; i<=2; i++)
        {
            if(guysArray[i].myRadioButton.Checked==true)
            {
                if (guysArray[i].myBet != null)
                {
                    guysArray[i].ClearBet();
                }
                guysArray[i].PlaceBet((int)BetAmountUpDown.Value, (int)DogNumberUpDown.Value);
                guysArray[i].myBet.bettingGuy = guysArray[i];
                guysArray[i].ChangeLabel();
                guysArray[i].ChangeRadio();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems to me, that I've initialized both guysArray and greyhound array in the same way, but on greyhoundsArray[0]... line I get an index out of range error and I can't figure out why.

Comment: Can you try `Guy[] guysArray = new Guy[2];` and `Greyhound[] greyhoundsArray=new Greyhound[3];` inside `ADayAtTheRacesForm()` method.

Comment: I get it now, I’ve thought that [x] meant the last index in the array instead of the number of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Guy[2]` is length 2, so positions (indices) 0 and 1. You can't assign to position 2, since that would be the third element in an array of length 2. So: `new Guy[3]`.

Likewise the other array: increase the length by one.

Alternatively; use array initializer syntax to create and initialize the arrays in one step without ever specifying the length:

```cs
guysArray = new [] {
    new Guy { myName="Joe", MyCashInBank=50, myRadioButton=JoeRadioButton, myLabel=JoeBetLable, myBet=null },
    new Guy { myName = "Rob", MyCashInBank = 75, myRadioButton = RobRadioButton, myLabel = RobBetLabel, myBet = null },
    new Guy { myName = "Al", MyCashInBank = 45, myRadioButton = AlRadioButton, myLabel = AlBetLabel, myBet = null },
};
```